# How is my language exposed when im on the web?

Tags: vpn, browser, language-support, privacy

This is driving me nuts. I use a VPN (that protects against leaks and shuts down internet in case it suddenly stops working) and then go to https://whatismyipaddress.com/ to confirm that it actually works, and yes it does. My IP address is changed to a US one. However, when I go on websites, it asks directly if I want to change to German. I go to microsoft.com and everything is in German without me having accepted it. It also happens on other sites.
Location services are disabled on Ubuntu and I have denied firefox access to everything. The browser privacy level is set to Strict. I have deleted history and cookies, restarted the browser, but it remains. And everytime I go to check if my ip is still in UK, indeed it is. I was in Poland a couple of weeks ago and even there the same happened but nothing was in Polish, everything in German like now. So my location is actually not leaked, but somehow they know my language.

Is this because of language settings in Ubuntu? I have both English and German as input sources but have now had it on English.

Can anyone please answer this?

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser submits your preferred languages to web servers.

You can configure that e.g. in Firefox in the "*General*" ("*Allgemein*" in German) page in the "*Language and Appearance*") ("*Sprache und Erscheinungsbild*") section, paragraph "*Language*" ("*Sprache*"), with the "*Choose...*" ("*Wählen...*") button.

Other web browsers should have similar settings.

Comment: Thank you, I found it. If I understand correctly, this means that the websites I have visited up until now have gotten the information about my preferred language (thus compromised my privacy). Or have the changes to German been done locally on my browser?